# Disqus: Subscribing a User to a Thread via PHP

Tags: php, disqus, subscribe

I'm using Disqus basically as the "wall" for users on my website. Note I'm not using wordpress or anything similar, a "custom" so to speak disqus implementation.

http://disqus.com

When a user registers I'd like to be able to subscribe them to the disqus thread associated with their own profile page so they'll get email notifications. I imagined it would be something along the lines of SUBSCRIBE_BY_EMAIL($user_email,$thread_id). I was not able to find any such function in the disqus documentation, or through internet searching.

Help?

If you're still confused what I mean feel free to take a look at the user profile pages on my website:

http://www.orderofprestige.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to use the [Disqus Web API](http://disqus.com/api/docs/), optionally with their own [PHP implementation](https://github.com/disqus/disqus-php), for this. If they have no public API for it, you are most probably out of luck (that is, if you don't use client-side black hat JavaScript like Clickjacking).